# Create letters as geometry polygons from SVG files?

Tags: qgis, polygon-creation

After searching a lot and not finding a definitive direction, is there a way to create geometry for a map that contains letters? I want text that is not a label or a symbol but lays flat as geometry on a map at a GPS location. So I am thinking that I can take SVG outline letters and convert them to polygons. Any advice on how to accomplish this? I want something like this:

[image]

Comment: Would a text field in print layout fit for what you want to do?

Comment: You could add a raster showing your letters, georeference it and then polygonize it.

Comment: In reply to babel: I am new to QGIS so my understanding of a print layout is limited (https://docs.qgis.org/3.4/en/docs/training_manual/map_composer/map_composer.html) but I want the user to be able to "drive" or traverse the map but also be able to pan and zoom the argument map and not just see the text when in a print mode.

Comment: In reply to MrXsquared: I am new to GIS so my understanding of rasterizing the text (creating and image) might work but wouldn't it be better to have the text and surrounding polygon rectangles as vectors so they scale better? Or maybe just show the rectangles when zoomed out and the rasterized text when zoomed in?

Comment: Thats what i meant by polygonizing (vectorizing) the raster

Comment: So are it sounds like you are suggesting the second solution: to display the text as raster images? If so, can you point me to resources on how to do that? And also resources on how to create the polygon from a csv?

Comment: It seems like I could use a geojson file to create the polygons: https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc7946#section-1.5

Comment: No, i am suggesting to display the text as polygons. Add a raster with your text and vectorize it.